# When does:$(p^y+1 )\bmod (p^x+1)=0 $ if $(y,x)=1$ and $p $ is a prime number?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, diophantine-equations

I'm interesting to look the solution of this equation :$$(p^y+1 )\bmod (p^x+1)=0  $$ at a least to see an example  of the two coprime $y, x$ for which $(p^y+1 )\bmod (p^x+1)=0  $ but i don't succed , I tried to check wolfram alpha for $y=3$ and $x=2$ for the fisrt list of prime numbers but i don't accross any example of that .

My question :Is there any pair of the two coprime $(x,y)$ satisfy the Equation:

$$(p^y+1 )\bmod (p^x+1)=0  $$ ?
**Note**:I have tried to use some definition of diaphontine equation (elliptic curve or any similar of that ) but no result

Thank you for any  help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No such examples exist.
\begin{align*}
p^y+1=0(\text{mod } p^x+1)
&\iff p^x+1|p^y+1\\
&\iff p^x+1|p^y-p^x\\
&\iff p^x+1|p^x(p^{y-x}-1)\\
&\iff p^x+1|p^{y-x}-1\\
&\iff p^x+1|p^{y-x}+p^x\\
&\iff p^x+1|p^x(p^{y-2x}+1)\\
&\iff p^x+1|p^{y-2x}+1\\
&\cdots\\
&\iff p^x+1|p^{y\text{ mod } x}\pm 1
\end{align*}

And the last line doesn't hold since the RHS is smaller than the LHS. In the circumstances where the equation holds, this last line has $y=0\text{ (mod }x)$ and the $\pm 1$ is a $-1$ so that the RHS is $0$. The statement $(x,y)=1$ rules this out. This proof also gives a necessary and sufficient condition for the equation, as the RHS being $0$ is the only way this division can work.

Comment: it is a nice idea